# Range variable vs Paragraph variable different behaviour with selection

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-word

I thought the two following programs would be identical, why arent they?

This code works:

```
For i = 1 To n
    Set r = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i).Range
    r.Collapse
    r.Text = " "
    r.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)
Next i
```

This code doesn't:

```
For i = 1 To n
    Set r = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i).Range
    Set p = r.Paragraphs(1)
    p.Range.Text = " " + p.Range.Text
    r.Collapse
    r.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)
Next i
```

As far as I can tell, the only difference is instead of concatenating the old text behind a space then placing the cursor at the start of the para, I just place the cursor at the start of the para and input a space.

**Tl;dr: I don't understand why the two programs above aren't equivalent**

I lack the general knowledge to google the reason. My attempts pulled up general purpose guides. I tried stepping through the debugger to get a grasp of the control flow, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim sel As Range


Set sel = Selection.Range

For i = 1 To n
    Set r = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i).Range
    Set p = r.Paragraphs(1)
    p.Range.Text = " " + p.Range.Text
    r.Collapse
    r.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlCheckBox)
    sel.Select
Next i
```

The problem is that:

p.Range.Text = " " + p.Range.Text

is changing the selection....

**** Edited to include better explanation****

When you use r.Collapse - you are setting the range r to have equal start and end positions.

For example if you have a paragraph like so:

"This is my first paragraph"

when you set r, it has a start of 0 and an end of 27. After you run r.Collapse the start and end both become 0 (assuming the para is at the start of the document).

You then insert a space (under your first method) at position 0 and then add your content control. Word can cope with this whilst the selection is selected.

Under the second method, you are changing the text of a paragraph directly. You are collapsing r later, but that will not change p. P will be range 0,27 to start. Word cannot change range (0,27) to be (0,28) by adding the space without selecting it.

In short, the difference is the collapse causing Word being able to insert the space before what is (to Word) a null range at that time.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to asnwer.

Ive already got it working, but I need help understand why. Can you elaborate on 'Its changing the selection'? Why does it do that? Arent I just manipulating the string within, not the selection?

Im guessing your code snippet avoids changing the selection somehow?

Comment: this line of code:

    Set r = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i).Range

is based on what is currently selected in the document.

The first method you posted keeps everything selected. When you say in the second method p.Range.Text that becomes the selection. So when you loop the next time it is trying to find paragraph n in a tiny selection and it won't exist.

My method is storing the original selection as a range at the start and then selecting it again at the end of each loop

Comment: I understand, thank you. Why does it do that? Why does manipulating the text narrow the selection down? Youve backed up the full selection, then you revert back to it at the end of every cycle. Is this the only solution?

Comment: My main confusion:

Why does messing with the range of a paragraph variable within a range variable change the full selection, but completely collapsing the main range variable doesnt affect the selection at all?

Comment: Because the VBA is causing the physical selection of the place in the document. It's the same as if you manually typed in the document.

Comment: Why does it not physically select when Im manipulating the range of a range variable instead of a paragraph variable? Ive marked this as the answer since you gave me a starting point at least, thanks. If you could continue helping till Ive grasped it that would be nice, if you have time.